# COM related Exception 0x80010106 (Cannot change thread mode after it is set) when calling CurrentApp:LicenseInformation->IsActive

Tags: c++, exception, com, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8

When I run the Windows Phone 8 project it crashes on this line:

```
CurrentApp::LicenseInformation->IsActive;
```

The error message is Microsoft C++ exception: Platform::COMException ^ at memory location 0x00ABE848. HRESULT:0x80010106 (Cannot change thread mode after it is set).

The error code is detailed here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824480 but I don't understand what I can do because I am calling a function which seems to wrap some COM initialisation.

Comment: Sloppy error.  Not much you can do about it, you have to call this code on the right thread.

Comment: The thing is, I haven't explicitly created any threads, so how do I find the thread to call it on, if not my main thread?

Comment: @reapz try one of the threads in the ThreadPool. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.threading.aspx

Comment: Use the debugger.  Debug + Windows + Threads.